# Opportunity analyze

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, analytics, aggregate

I need an analyze of our opportunities for each team in our org.
First I select the team and then should the visual page show a table of all accountOwner of this team and the different recordtypes (productgroups).

The first row should show the different recordtypes and the first column should  show the accountOwner. Looks like an excel-table.

Below you will find my code, but the result is not working very well.

```
<table class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr class="headerRow">
      <td></td>
      <apex:repeat value="{!RTypeList}" var="rt">
          <td>{!rt.Name}</td>
      </apex:repeat>
  </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!UserList}" var="u">
  <tr>
    <td>{!u.Name}</td>
      <apex:repeat value="{!Summaries}" var="v">
    <td>{!v.Value}</td>
      </apex:repeat>
  </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>



Public List <RecordType> getRTypeList() {
  RTypeList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Opportunity'];
  RETURN RTypeList;
}    

Public List <User> getUserList() {
  UserList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Team__c = :SelectedTeamId];
  RETURN UserList;
}   

Public void getauswertung() {
  getRTypeList();
  getUserList();
  getInformation();
}

Public void getInformation() {
  Summaries = new List<Summary>();
  FOR (User UserName : UserList) {
    FOR (RecordType RType : RTypeList) {
    AggregateResult[] Results = [SELECT Account.Owner.Name accOwner, RecordType.Name oppProduct, SUM(Amount) PlanValue FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId = :RType.Id AND Account.Owner.Id = :UserName.Id GROUP BY Account.Owner.Name, RecordType.Name];
      FOR (AggregateResult ar : Results) {
      Summaries.ADD(new Summary(ar));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**23.07.2015**

I think I need a combination of all three loops.
For example - in cell B2 should show the value of User[0].RType[0].value. Is this possible?

Comment: You need to create what's referred to as a wrapper class that nests these various items you're trying to iterate on.

Comment: Ok, may you help me with the code. Because I have no ideas how can I code this.

Comment: I recommend you search SF.SE for "wrapper class" or use http://findsf.info/ to find examples and perhaps even a tutorial on wrapper classes to see if you can code it yourself starting from what you already have.

Comment: crmprogdev could you explain me what do you mean with sf.se?

Comment: SF.SE is right here on Salesforce.StackExchange. Look above at the URL in your browser. Here's 2 useful links for you to info on wrapper classes: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class and https://salesforcebyexperts.wordpress.com/salesforce-wrapper-classes/.